# HTML label hides nearest control

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

I have the following html code

```
<html>
   <script>
      function test(){              
        document.getElementById('lblUser').innerText="test html";                   
      }
  </script>     
  <a href="#">LINK1</a>
  <label id="lblUser"/>         
  <a href="#">LINK2</a>
  <script type="text/javascript">test();</script>       
</html>
```

While calling **test()** LINK2 disappears. It seems to be because of the change in **lblUser.innerText**. But what's the possible way to show LINK2? And why this happens?

Comment: Also, you lack a HEAD and BODY in your HTML.

Comment: I am pretty sure regardless of doctype that label is not self closing.

Comment: in xhtml technically any tag can be self-closing.

Comment: i have modified the code with <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> with no success

Comment: I think <label> can never be self closing

Comment: its a browser thing - the spec says any tag can can be self-closing, but browsers use a more sensible implementation. Setting its innerHTML is breaking but if you were setting an attribute (id for example) would work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label's implementation depends on doctype, try not having label as a self-closing tag.

```
  <label id="lblUser"></label> 

  <a href="#">LINK2</a>

  <script>
      function test(){              
        document.getElementById('lblUser').innerText="test html";                   
      }
      test();
  </script>
```

Comment: but whats the relation with doc type?

Comment: Without going into too much depth, it basically depends if it's XHTML or HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Label tags are not self closing.

Therefore, your browser sees it as a container surrounding the text2 element and when you set the HTML, the inner content of the label gets removed which is why text2 is gone.

You should have it as:

```
<label id="lblUser">...</label>
```